# getting "EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Index [petrol/petrolCat] missing and settings" while loding data from hive to ES

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive, kibana, hiveql

Can someone please help me to solve this error. Due to this exception I unable to load hive data to Elastic Search.

--Hive console code

```
    Hive>
        > create external table  petrol_es(distributer_id STRING,distributer_name STRING,amt_IN STRING,amy_OUT STRING,vol_IN INT,vol_OUT INT,year INT)
        > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe'
        > STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
        > tblproperties('es.resource' = 'petrol/petrolCat');
    OK
    Time taken: 0.16 seconds
    hive>
        >
        > select * from petrol_es;
    OK
    Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Index [petrol/petrolCat] missing and settings [es.field.read.empty.as.null] is set to false
    Time taken: 0.156 seconds
    hive>
        >
        >
```

Comment: Did you try to set parameter es.field.read.empty.as.null to true?

Comment: When I added below properties then this issue was resolved -------'es.index.auto.create' = 'true','es.index.read.missing.as.empty'='yes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved after adding 'es.index.auto.create' = 'true','es.index.read.missing.as.empty'='yes' properties.

--DDL

```
    create external table  petrol_es(distributer_id STRING,distributer_name STRING,amt_IN STRING,amy_OUT STRING,vol_IN INT,vol_OUT INT,year INT)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe'
    STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
    tblproperties('es.resource' = 'petrol/petrolCat','es.index.auto.create' = 'true','es.index.read.missing.as.empty'='yes');
```